If one shoves a compressed air nozzle into a tap, then the tap water freezes
As seen here on this youtube video: https://youtu.be/B-Zi73oBDZE?si=ZvF3y4Mc6qfQP2GD&t=145
Why does this happen ?
Details for those wanting them: image an electronics compressed gas duster (like "Dust Off"). It has a long nozzle coming out of a can. If gas from the nozzle is blown up a tap of water (the nozzle is pushed up the tap), then why does water get frozen so drastically? For freezing, either temperature should be low or pressure should be super high. But while I can understand that water kept in a container when subjected to huge pressure can freeze. How does pressure from the nozzle get applied on freely flowing water, enough to freeze it (given the cross section of the nozzle is so small and cross section of the tap is substantially larger)?

What is the question?

https://essay.utwente.nl/75434/1/InternshipReport.pdf discusses CO2 expansion and how cold it gets.

A "Why is such the case" question can only be answered with you supplying how reality is not matching your expectations. Because we cannot access your internal model of reality, and you have not given us what exactly it is that is confusing you here, or what needs explaining, the only possible answer to the question "Why dis?" is:
"Just cuz".

@AnthonyKhodanian: No please! This is genuine question. Let me edit it.

@AnthonyKhodanian: I have edited the question for your viewing pleasure. Pleace let it remain open dis time

@PM2Ring: Thx for feedback. I have edited the question to clarify the phrase u quoted

Although the products like that shown are often called "canned air", they don't have compressed air inside.   Most have something very similar to difluoroethane.  It's stored in the can as a liquid, but has a boiling point of -25C at atmospheric pressure.
When the valve is opened with the can held upside down, the liquid is forced through the valve instead of just the vapor.   At atmospheric pressure, it rapidly boils, causing cooling.
